# Asymptotic behavior of Fourier cosine transform $f(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\beta(t)\sin(\frac{t\pi}{2})\cos(tx)dt$

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-series, fourier-transform, approximation-theory

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ :
$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\beta(t)\sin(\frac{t\pi}{2})\cos(tx)dt.$$

Assuming $\beta(t)\sim\displaystyle\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}$ for $t\to+\infty$  is it true that for $x\to0$
$$f(x)\sim\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}\sin(\frac{t\pi}{2})\cos(tx)dt\,?$$
Namely, the values of the function $f(x)$ at a small value of $x$ are mainly dependent on the large $t$ behavior of their coefficient. How to prove it?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What are the 2 functions you mention in your first sentence ?

Comment: @Jean Marie sorry, there is only one function $f(x)$

Comment: Why would you believe this?

Comment: @Mark Viola  I am not sure, I saw it in an old note of one of the senior scientists. I could not find any justification for this step. However, if eliminating the oscillatory factor $\sin(\pi t/2)$, it seems to be true.

Comment: Have you attempted to replace $\sin(\frac{t\pi}{2})\cos(tx)$ by $\frac12(\sin t(x+\pi/2)-\sin t(x-\pi/2))$ ?

Comment: Btw, why do you call it a Fourier integral ? Do you mean the "Fourier **cosine** transform" of $U(t)\beta(t)\sin(\frac{t\pi}{2})$ ? where $U$ is the Heaviside function ?

Comment: @Jean Marie thank you for your comment. Yes, I have tried, but I don't know how to go from this step.  do you have any idea about this? thank you

Comment: @Jean Marie Yes, it should be " Fourier cosine transform", let me correct it now.

Comment: Sorry, no supplementary idea...